# Why are ThreadPoolExecutor tasks stopping randomly?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm currently using a ThreadPoolExecutor to run a big quantity of I/O tasks. The code works fine but it looks like some of the threads die after running for a little while.

```
def start_threads(thread_count, base_filepath):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=thread_count + 2) as executor:
        results = []
        results.append(executor.submit(print_manager))
        for i in range(thread_count):
            results.append(executor.submit(tester, f'{base_filepath}.{i+1}', i+1))
        print(f"All {thread_count} threads started, waiting for results...")
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            print(future.result())
```

The print_manager function keeps on running, but all the other tasks (testers) seem to be stopping after some time. They are infinite loops and do not return anything so I don't understand why they are stopping. Is there a way to stop that from happening, or restart the threads when they die ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tester tasks are infinite loops and they are stopping after running for a while, it's possible that they are encountering an unhandled exception or encountering some other issue that causes them to terminate. Since you mentioned that these tasks do not return anything, it can be challenging to determine the exact cause without additional information.

Here are a few suggestions to help you investigate and address the issue:

Add exception handling within the tester function: Wrap the code inside your tester function with a try-except block and handle any exceptions that might occur. This way, you can catch any exceptions and log or print them to identify the cause of the termination. For example:
Enable logging: Use the Python logging module to log any exceptions or other relevant information during the execution of your tester tasks. You can configure the logging level and log to a file or the console for easier debugging.

Verify resource limitations: As mentioned in the previous response, it's worth checking if there are any resource limitations that might be causing the threads to terminate. Monitor system resources such as file handles, memory usage, or network connections to ensure you're not hitting any limits.

```python
import concurrent.futures
import threading

def tester(file_path, index):
    while True:
        try:
            # Your code logic here
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An exception occurred in tester {index}: {str(e)}")

def monitor_threads(executor):
    while True:
        if executor._work_queue.qsize() < thread_count:
            print("Restarting terminated threads...")
            for i in range(thread_count - executor._work_queue.qsize()):
                executor.submit(tester, f'{base_filepath}.{i+1}', i+1)
        time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the sleep duration as per your needs

def start_threads(thread_count, base_filepath):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=thread_count + 2) as executor:
        results = []
        results.append(executor.submit(print_manager))
        for i in range(thread_count):
            results.append(executor.submit(tester, f'{base_filepath}.{i+1}', i+1))

        # Start thread monitoring
        threading.Thread(target=monitor_threads, args=(executor,), daemon=True).start()

        print(f"All {thread_count} threads started, waiting for results...")
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            print(future.result())
```

Comment: Thank you ! The uncaught exception seems to be a very plausible solution. I'll try that out asap and i'll let you know if that works !

Comment: All good. If you can or want to pls vote my answer.

Comment: So yeah, it turns out I was not catching some exceptions causing the threads to stop. Now I know that they are not printed if they happen in a worker thread ! Thanks for the help !

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).